# SQL: Closest timestamp to max(timestamp)

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, mysql-5.7, dbeaver

I am looking for the date from one table that is closest to the maximum date of another table. So the closest event.end timestamp to max(timestamp) from another table. Currently i'm trying it in this way:

```
SELECT
  users.id as userID,
  users.created_at as AccountCreation,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,users.created_at,max(app2xpr_analytics.logs_api_requests.timestamp))as ActiveDays,
  max(app2xpr_analytics.logs_api_requests.timestamp) as LaatsteLogin,
  max(events.`end`) as LaatsteEvent
FROM 
  users
LEFT JOIN app2xpr_analytics.logs_api_requests ON app2xpr_analytics.logs_api_requests.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN checkins ON checkins.id_user = users.id
LEFT JOIN events ON checkins.id_event = events.id_event
WHERE events.`end` < max(app2xpr_analytics.logs_api_requests.timestamp)
GROUP BY users.id LIMIT 10;
```

This doesn't work (invalid group function) However, I've also tried

```
MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF,DAY,events.`end`,max(app2xpr_analytics.logs_api_requests.timestamp)
```

which didn't work either.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Some product specific SQL there...

Comment: It's not clear whether you want the absolute maximum of all logs_api_request timestamps or the maximum for each user_id; the query says the second, but the alias suggests the first....

Comment: The first one indeed. I want the event.`end` date that is the closest to the last request made by each user individually. E.g., User 1 has 5 recorded events, and his last request was 2017/03/03. I then want to find the date of the event that is closest to this value. Or the difference between the two is fine as well.

Comment: I'm afraid we will need some sample data and the expected result